# Reorder a running count in a vector

Tags: r, vector

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to do this that doesn't require a for loop.

I have a vector of data that increases sequentially, but skips occasional values. For example,  test

```
num[1:4651] 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 7 7 9 9 9 9, etc.
```

Is there an R function that will convert that vector into a fixed sequence starting at 1 through the end of the vector? So,

```
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4, etc.
```

Comment: ``inverse.rle(list(values = 1:length(unique(x)), lengths = rle(x)$lengths))``

Comment: @d.b More standard: `inverse.rle(with(rle(x), list(values = seq_along(values), lengths = lengths)))`

Answer (score 4):

We can use `match` to do this

```
match(test, unique(test))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

---

Or another option is `factor`

```
as.integer(factor(test, levels = unique(test)))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

---

As @Frank suggested, `dense_rank` from `dplyr` may also work as the values are increasing

```
dplyr::dense_rank(test)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

If the values are not repeating again, possibly `rleid` can be used

```
data.table::rleid(test)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

Or a `base R` option using `rle`

```
inverse.rle(within.list(rle(test), values <- seq_along(values)))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

Or another option is

```
cumsum(c(TRUE, test[-1] != test[-length(test)]))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

Or with `lag` from `dplyr`

```
cumsum(test != lag(test, default = TRUE))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

#### data

```
test <- c(2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works!

Answer (score 3):

Using `rle` and `rep` in base R where `vec` is your vector:

```
with(rle(vec), rep(seq_along(lengths), times = lengths))
```